# What kind of contamination shows a white film with dots in secondary?

Tags: beer, fruit, contamination, saison

[image: 2 days ago]
[image: Now]

Hi!

Okay, so around month ago I made a saison with some mixed frozen strawberries (1 week in the freezer) added to the primary fermentation (fermented with S.Cerevisiae strain). After three weeks I've transferred the beer for the secondary fermentation. After a week the beer got covered by white coating with weird white "dots" arriving in groups of few (as seen on 1st picture). I'd say it looks a bit like Pediococcus, but I have not seen those dots in any P. contamination on the internet. Do you guys have an idea what is this weird thing?

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to say what is making the pellicle.

But as for your white dots, they are too uniform for an organic IMO.

I would say they are **just co2 bubbles** trapped under the pellicle.